# Duplicate and Unknown in SSAS Cube

Tags: sql, ssas, cube

I was browsing my cube and noticed that when I try to filter out Customers by Postal Code there are few cases where the Postal Code is duplicated while not containing any values.

For example I could have 90210 Beverly Hills (which would work fine and give me the correct results) and the next in line would be 90210 Boston (Which would not give any results). The cube has worked before without any errors, so not sure why the sudden errors.

What is a possible reason for this error?

Comment: What do you mean "not containing any values"? What customer has 90210 Boston? Need more info. There are too many questions to ask you.

Comment: So basically when I  filter by postal code, my cube is now showing extra fields for example 90210 Boston (which it shouldn't be doing). But the thing is that inside those new fields there is of course no value. I am just wondering why those new fields are appearing.

Comment: Are you currently in Visual Studio / Cube Browser when "filtering"? What's your schema like? Do the Postal Codes live in your Customer Dimension, or in another location such as Location? etc... Have you added any new data/fields since the last time it worked? Have you processed? etc...

Comment: I am currently viewing the cube as a Pivot Table in Excel and have added data since it last worked. Might it have something to do with a foreign key that is not availible?

Comment: Need more info. Does Postal Code live in DimCustomer? If not, then where? What have you changed since it last worked? What foreign key is not available and where?